# how do i write only one jquery click function for handling multiple items inside a slider?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

i have a question:
i have a slider on my website and within each slider item i show an image and a bandcamp iframe link.

following code is one of the slider items:

```
<div class="tapecol col-md-4">
    <img class="media-object round" id="compi7" src="images/artworks/ep/compilation7.png">
    <div class="eptitle">
    </div>
    <row class="caption-row">
        <iframe class="bandcamp" id="compi7bandcamp">"IFRAMECODE"</iframe>
    </row>
</div>
```

When the user clicks onto the image (id="compi7") it shows the iframe (id="compi7bandcamp") within the item. but i do it seperatly for each item, **because the user should only see the iframe of the current item image clicked on.**

At first i only had 5 items, so i wrote a funcion for each slider item there is, but now i have 11 and i will get even more items in the future, so i want to have 1 function to handle all items.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#compi1").click(function(event){           
    $("#compi1bandcamp").slideToggle( 500 );
  });

  $("#compi2").click(function(event){           
    $("#compi2bandcamp").slideToggle( 500 );
  });

  $("#compi3").click(function(event){           
    $("#compi3bandcamp").slideToggle( 500 );
  });

  $("#compi4").click(function(event){           
    $("#compi4bandcamp").slideToggle( 500 );
  });

  $("#compi5").click(function(event){           
    $("#compi5bandcamp").slideToggle( 500 );
  }); 

  $("#compi6").click(function(event){           
    $("#compi6bandcamp").slideToggle( 500 );
  });

  $("#compi7").click(function(event){           
    $("#compi7bandcamp").slideToggle( 500 );
  }); 

});
```

how can i achieve this, to use one function for every item in my slider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use some generic classes instead of numbered ones, you can just have 1 function

```
<div class="tapecol col-md-4">
    <img class="media-object round compi" id="compi7" src="images/artworks/ep/compilation7.png">
    <div class="eptitle">
    </div>
    <row class="caption-row">
        <iframe class="bandcamp" id="compi7bandcamp">"IFRAMECODE"</iframe>
    </row>
</div>
```

The above uses a class `compi` on the image and class `bandcamp` on the element you're trying to target.

```
$(".compi").click(function(event){           
    $(this).parent().find('.bandcamp').slideToggle( 500 );
});
```